# Generate a combination of characters using python

Tags: python

```
from itertools import combinations
f = open('snc.csv', 'w')
for comb in combinations(range('1','20'), 5):
    f.write(str(comb))
    f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

My scripts works with numbers, i want it work with characters too from a to f, in range of 4, no repetition, no shuffling, like so

A,b,c,d,e

A,b,c,d,f

A,b,c,e,f

And so one, it always starts with a, if a doesn't exist in the range of 4, then it stats with b, order is important,  so much like the script above

Comment: I'm marking this as off-topic since it is a pure programming question and has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: @muru note  taken, won't happen again, how about migrating it to SO or programming.SE or something like that then?

Comment: You could flag this question for moderator attention asking for migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations
f = open('snc.csv', 'w')
for comb in combinations(range(26), 4):
    f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % tuple([chr(x + ord('a')) for x in comb]))
f.close()
```

**EDIT** This one will also work and is probably a little easier to read:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import combinations
f = open('snc.csv', 'w')
for comb in combinations(ascii_lowercase, 4):
    f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % comb)
f.close()
```

Comment: the first snippet outputs `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "charcom.py", line 4, in <module>
    f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % tuple([chr(x + ord('a')) for x in comb]))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
`

Comment: the second one outputs strings that contains i and m and all the characters, how to limit it to just from a to f?

Comment: replace `combinations(ascii_lowercase, 4)` with `combinations('abcdef', 4)`